# Regarding Hardware Access using C++ and VB.net

Tags: c++, vb.net

I currently have basic knowledge of C++ and VB.Net.

For our college project i plan to do something related to Accessing Hardware.

I would like to know about some Libraries and functions that can be used to access the monitor and hard disk (Master Boot Record actually) using:

1. C++
2. VB.Net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the Answer for C++ using WIN APIs and call these programs in VB